# Display a view block with a list of content excluding the one currently displayed on the page

Tags: views, 8, blocks

I sometimes use contextual filters to display fields matching the content ID from url

In that case , i would like to display a list of content as a view block , except the one that is displayed

It would require to :

- negate the condition " Content ID from URL contextual filters "

or

- being able to choose the 'content id from url' as value of a view filter

I don't know how to do the first option.
That token conditions module would do for the second option but is not stable
https://www.drupal.org/project/token_conditions

How can i possibly do that then except JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the first option, it is simple :

add a contextual filter of type "ID: Content" with the following configuration :

- WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE > provide a default value > content id from url
- Go all the way down in the "more" section, expand it and check "exclude".
- Then click apply
- And save the views

That's it !